# Parse XML for image data and return the image string

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing, return

I am having a slight logic issue. I am parsing an XML file returned from an api call to display in  list box. The xml data returns an object key not the actual image. I then have to use the opject key to call another function that returns a xml with the image data parse that image data and return it to the previous function. I am able to successfully parse the data into a IEnumerable List but i'm not sure how to return the image string to the previous call.

```
                try
                {
                   // MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
                    XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
                    var data = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("interaction")
                               select new Interaction
                               {
                                   title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                                   displayName = (string)query.Element("displayName"),
                                   action = (string)query.Element("action"),
                                   verb = (string)query.Element("verb"),
                                   userId = (string)query.Element("userId"),
                                   objectKey = (string)query.Element("objectKey"),
                                   timestamp = (string)query.Element("timestamp"),
                                   comment = (string)query.Element("comment"),
                                   source = (string)query.Element("source"),                            
                                   profileImage = "http://adb.s3.amazonaws.com/" + (string)query.Element("userId") + "/avatar.png",
                                   image = getImage((string)query.Element("objectKey")),
                               };



                    streamListBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

The above code snippet is the first function that binds the data to the list box. this works great except I need the images which is not in the xml response. I have to make a second function call - getImage- to get it with the object key. I would like the getImage function to return just the string for each object

```
                    try
                    {
                       // MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
                        XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));



                        var data = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("show")
                                   select new Interaction
                                   {
                                       image = (string)query.Element("image"),
                                   };

                        var data2 = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("movie")
                                    select new Interaction
                                    {
                                        image = (string)query.Element("image"),
                                    };

                        var data3 = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("artist")
                                    select new Interaction
                                    {
                                        image = (string)query.Element("image"),
                                    };



                        objImages = data.Concat(data2).Concat(data3);


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }

                });
            }
            return "HOW CAN I RETURN IMAGE STRING HERE";
        }
```

Comment: What is the data type of the "image" property in Interaction? Is it string? If it is string, then is it an URL? Or is it a encoded binary image? Also why are you concatenating data2, data3 in your second method?

Comment: Hi, the image property is a string url that I simply bind in the listbox. The concat is to combine the images from shows, movies and movies depending on which the user checks into.

Comment: foreach (Interaction element in objImages)
                          {
                              _objectImage = element.image;
                              sendImage(_objectImage);
                              
                          } I get all the urls outputted as string. The problem is the scope is such that I cannot use a return statement such as return _objectImage

Comment: Your property "image" for a single image, why do need to send back 3 at a time? If you need to send back three, then why not have a List<string> instead?

Comment: Hi, 3 isn't sent back at a time the other two is in case the objectkey represents a tv show, movie or a music since the decendants are different. Only one image per object key is returned (the others would be empty)